# How to generate Excel sheet from drl file

Tags: drools

I was looking for drools api to generate excel sheet from drl file, is this possible? if yes please can someone point me at the API's?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Iḿ not sure that you can make it directly from drools, maybe you should check the api that drools uses to read and build rules from excel files. Take a look here http://code.google.com/p/red-piranha/

Comment: Any update on this with Drools 5.5?